# Google Maps Android -- How access default infowindow?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map that shows a few points. If the user searches for a location instead of using their default location, a placemark will show for the searched location as well. This placemark shows the infowindow by default. All of these points are shown on screen (using a bounding box).

However, although I can account for the placemark to be shown on screen inside a bounding box, I am currently unable to make sure its infowindow is completely visible on screen. For example, if the placemark is the northeast-most item, its infowindow will be overflowing off the screen both on the top and the right.

Is there any way to get the infowindow of a marker? I know I can build one out using the CustomWindowAdapter and later access that view, but I don't want to customize it at all, just to be able to access it (and not just be able to call show or hideinfowindow() from the marker).

Ideally, I could get the height and width of the infowindow in pixels and use that to make sure it is always completely shown on screen.

Comment: You may try to work this by using `Handler` and `Marker.showInfoWindow()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. What you see as "info window" inside the map view is nothing more than a buffered snapshot (or a screen dump if you will) of the view created by your InfoWindowAdapter, meaning it's not a traditional view added to the view hierarchy, rather it's an image shown in the OpenGL context.

Accessing or manipulating this view after showInfoWindow() won't make any difference to what gets displayed on the map, at least until you call showInfoWindow() again to take a new snapshot.

It's the same reason you cannot add a long-click listener to the info window.